# Bug in reputation graph (no reputation values for dates)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph, safari

In the screenshot you can see that there are no values in the small window in the graph!

Happens with **Safari Version 5.1.4 (7534.54.16)**

[image]

Comment: What browser version is that? (No repro on Chromium 18)

Comment: No repro with FF11.

Comment: I [brought it up in the Highcharts support forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16355), but no dice (or rerpo) there either. Is it still happening for you?

Comment: Yesterday it sill happens! But today I've made a restart of the hole system! Now everything is fine! Sorry for the trouble :-(

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this on my Mac (same Safari version).